# NSScrollView in a popup became transparent under MacOS Mojave

Tags: transparency, subview, nsscrollview, macos-mojave, nspopover

In a view displayed as a Popover, I implement a help subview (a NSView with a NSScrollView as a subview) that appears when user click on a button. With Sierra & High Sierra, everything was all right, but since I upgraded the dev MacPro to Mojave, the help bubble became slightly transparent. Elements (NSTextField or NSButton) being the help view are still visible as a white strip in Dark Mode (or as a gray strip in Light Mode)

[image: capture of the non-transparent view]

I have defined the help view and its scroll view to have their own layer  and these two layers are set as opaque

```
[help setWantsLayer:YES];
help.layer.opaque = TRUE;
help.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithRed:1. green:1. blue:140./255. alpha:1.];
[help.scrollView setWantsLayer:YES];
help.scrollView.layer.opaque = TRUE;
[help.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithRed:1. green:1. blue:140./255. alpha:1.]];
```

All background colours are set to this yellow tone.
This problem occurs only if the view that display the help view was presented as a NSPopover, not as a NSView from an ordinary window. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

add `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` = `YES` in your info.plist

To run any app in Dark Mode, you must to be running macOS Mojave 10.14 or greater. By default, all existing apps will run in Light Mode even if the system is configured to run in Dark Mode. An app that is launched on macOS Mojave will run in Dark Mode when two criteria are met:

The system considers the app to be compatible with Dark Mode
The running application’s appearance is set to Dark Aqua
An app’s compatibility with Dark Mode is determined by a combination of the SDK it was built against, and the value of the `“NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance”` Info.plist key. If your app is built against the 10.14 SDK or later, it will be considered compatible unless the key is set to `YES`. If your app is built against the 10.13 SDK or earlier, it is considered incompatible unless the Info.plist key is set to `NO`.

Comment: I tried both adding this key in the Info.plist, or setting appearance to the help view (and even its scroll view), but no change occur…

Comment: When the superview (of the help view) appearance is set to NSAppearanceNameAqua, the problem vanishes (logical, as the view and its subviews are automatically set like this, but using the Light mode). But when only the help view appearance is set to Aqua, the transparency is still there. I looks like a bug in Mojave, isn't it?

Comment: i don't think OS have issue you may found out with your code